# 2.91 problem: Why is texture paint painting draw a line like x symmetry is ebabled when it is not?

Tags: texturing

[image]

[image]

Somobody could answer what should I do to only draw one line? I only have this problem since the new version 2.91 came out. Maybe is it the brush type TextDraw or something?

Comment: Just a guess: Have you used a Mirror modifier? Have you uv unwrapped the whole model (and not a mirrored version)? Are there stacked uv islands?

Comment: No to every question. 